# Unicode text does not render in WSL Ubuntu

Tags: fonts, windows-subsystem-for-linux, unicode, utf-8

My installation of Ubuntu in WSL fails to render Unicode text. Below is a screenshot from [Sanskrit Wikipedia](https://sa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%96%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%83%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A0%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D).

How should I fix it?

[image: Sanskrit Wikipedia]

Comment: What browser do you use here? (In Microsoft Edge, and in Chrome, I  do not see a problem.  Also from what OS are your starting this browser, (just to make the question [on-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)... )

Comment: You seem to miss a font which is capable of rendering Sanskrit. Try to install the `fonts-noto-core` package.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: I do not have that installed, and fonts show correctly ... (so, no need in trying)

Comment: @Luuk: Then you have some other font with that capability, e.g. `fonts-lohit-deva`. "No need in trying" ... How is that helpful for an obvious font issue??

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson It worked!! Thanks a ton!! Could you please add it as an answer so that I can accept it? 

Comment: @RiteshSingh: Great! Please feel free to submit an answer yourself. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question. :)